btrfs: ERROR: Could not destroy subvolume/snapshot: Directory not empty
I can't remove btrfs subvolume:
$ btrfs property get /mnt/btrfs/@.broken
ro=false
$ sudo btrfs subvolume delete /mnt/btrfs/@.broken
Delete subvolume 256 (no-commit): '/mnt/btrfs/@.broken'
ERROR: Could not destroy subvolume/snapshot: Directory not empty

Any ideas what could be wrong? It's not read only.
I created this subvolume by renaming @ to @.broken and recreated the original @ from snapshot, because my system was broken. My current subvolumes are:
ID 256 gen 648983 top level 5 path @.broken
ID 257 gen 649030 top level 5 path @home
ID 258 gen 649016 top level 5 path @cache
ID 259 gen 649030 top level 5 path @log
ID 266 gen 648877 top level 5 path @home_kossak_work
ID 267 gen 649016 top level 5 path @home_kossak_main
ID 268 gen 649006 top level 5 path @home_kossak_apps
ID 296 gen 648224 top level 5 path @home_sslib
ID 619 gen 648881 top level 5 path @home_kossak_bigdata
ID 3756 gen 649011 top level 5 path timeshift-btrfs/snapshots/2024-05-25_11-16-53/@
ID 3757 gen 648240 top level 5 path timeshift-btrfs/snapshots/2024-05-25_11-53-00/@
ID 3763 gen 649030 top level 5 path @
ID 3764 gen 648998 top level 5 path snapshots/@.20240525_2230

and hundreds of docker subvolumes like:
ID 3753 gen 633821 top level 256 path @.broken/var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/kr0q4k0szfoacpcuni18kk82m

Should I remove docker subvolumes first (and recreate my docker images?) or maybe there's easy way to switch all these containers to @ subvolume? Or should I remove docker and reinstall it?

Should I remove docker subvolumes first AFAIK you can just mv them to (the same path under) @, if you want to keep them. @/var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/ (the current/new one) should be empty (well no subvolumes, at least) at the moment. Or should I remove docker and reinstall it? Utterly irrelevant.

I just removed all docker images and its btrfs subvolumes. Redownloaded only needed images and it works.
